# How do I test my pages in the AOL browser without installing AOL?

Tags: testing, web, aol

How can I test my site in AOL without installing AOL? I did that once on my machine, and it killed it... ;)

I know, I know... I can use a Virtual Machine, but I'm really just looking for an AOL Browser... a separate browser install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download [AOL Explorer](http://downloads.channel.aol.com/browser) by itself.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. Why would anybody use this? :)

Comment: I have two friends who still use it.  I run fast when they ask me to "take a look" at their computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted answer linked through to the generic downloads location, you can go directly to the product here: http://info.aol.co.uk/browser/